# Automatically select parameters of Hough Line Transform with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform, houghlinesp

I'm using the Hough lines transform to detect straight lines on an edges image:

`lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edge_image, rho, theta, threshold, minLineLength, maxLineGap)`

However all the parameters wildly depend on the image being used.

Is there a way to automatically select "optimal" parameters for a given image, based on its properties?

The edges were previously found using cv2.Canny.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [mre] required. that includes input data. untouched.

Comment: Thank you, I will add more information. However it was more like a general question, independent on the particular input data. For example for Canny edge detection, some parameters that depend on the image mean value work quite well for lots of different inputs (see for example: https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/04/06/zero-parameter-automatic-canny-edge-detection-with-python-and-opencv/). I was thinking more in a kind of rule of thumb like that one

Comment: That is not minimal reproducible example.  You need to show more code if not all your code for us to reproduce. But to answer your question I know of no way to automatically adjust the parameters per different images.